# How to sort XML records based on the timestamp tag in unix?

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have a requirement to sort XML tag value by name and not by position, as the xml tags are dynamic i.e the number of tags aren't fixed. So far I've tried below code but it fails to give the expected output.

```
$ sed  -e 's/<timestamp>/& /' file | sort -n -k2 | sed 's/ //g'
```

XML records :-

```
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:51:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data1>
<data1><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:49:32.511</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>BBB</name></data1>
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:54:30.540</timestamp><name>AAA</name></data1>
<data2><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data2>
<data2><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:41:33.540</timestamp><name>YYY</name></data2> 
<data2><Version>102</Version><newtag>xlc<newtag><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:12.510</timestamp><name>BBB</name></data2>
```

expected output :-

```
<data2><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:41:33.540</timestamp><name>YYY</name></data2> 
<data1><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:49:32.511</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>BBB</name></data1>
<data2><Version>102</Version><newtag>xlc<newtag><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:12.510</timestamp><name>BBB</name></data2>
<data2><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data2>
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:51:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data1>
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:54:30.540</timestamp><name>AAA</name></data1>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115607/2834978) for a proper XML handling of the issue with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` to split fields at `<[/]?timestamp>`, populate an array with timestamp as key and then sort it. This assumes records are in a single line.

`gawk 'BEGIN{FS="<[/]?timestamp>"}{ts[$2]=$1 "<timestamp>" $2 "</timestamp>" $3}END{ n=asorti(ts,kts); for (i=1;i<=n;i++){ print ts[kts[i]]}}' tmp.xml`

Result

```
<data2><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:41:33.540</timestamp><name>YYY</name></data2> 
<data1><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:49:32.511</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>BBB</name></data1>
<data2><Version>102</Version><newtag>xlc<newtag><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:12.510</timestamp><name>BBB</name></data2>
<data2><Version>102</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:50:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data2>
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:51:33.540</timestamp><newtag>xlc<newtag><name>XXX</name></data1>
<data1><Version>101</Version><timestamp>2022-11-01T05:54:30.540</timestamp><name>AAA</name></data1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly if you remove the `-n` switch from sort:

```
sed  -e 's/<timestamp>/& /' file | sort -k2 | sed 's/ //g'
```