# Python : Sort xml file by tag content

Tags: python, xml, sorting, elementtree

I have this .xml example as input:

```
<root>
   <user>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>xyz</name>
   </user>
   <user>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>abc</name>
   </user>
</root>
```

How can I sort the "users" by "id" number to get the following .xml as output:

```
<root>
   <user>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>abc</name>
   </user>
   <user>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>xyz</name>
   </user>
</root>
```

I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Can you use lxml instead of elementtree?

Comment: [Sorting based on element text with lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115607/2834978)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy
xml = '''<root>
   <user>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>xyz</name>
   </user>
   <user>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>abc</name>
   </user>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
users = root.findall('user')
clone = users.copy()
for user in users:
    root.remove(user)
clone.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.find('id').text),reverse=False)
for user in clone:
    root.append(user)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<root>
   <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>abc</name>
   </user>
   <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>xyz</name>
   </user>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<root>
   <user>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>xyz</name>
   </user>
   <user>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>abc</name>
   </user>
</root>"""

def key(e):
    return int(e.find('id').text)

_xml = ET.fromstring(xml)
root = ET.Element('root')

for user in sorted(_xml.findall('user'), key=key):
    root.append(user)

ET.indent(root, space='  ')
ET.dump(root)
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
  <user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>abc</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>xyz</name>
  </user>
</root>
```